# How To Input Data from dynamic number of fields in html form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

this code is to create dynamic number of fields and to send data.. this is doing it's work...
but then i try to back.php(where form sends the data ) i don't know hoe to get the exact number of rows... id = 0_1 .... 3_1 there are many options.. but what is the exact number to counting to make a loop...
please help  me on this asap ...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Infinite Form Rows</title>
        <script 
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://cachefile.net/scripts/jquery/1.2.3/jquery-1.2.3.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            var newRowNum = 0;


            $('#addnew').click(function(){

                newRowNum += 1;


                var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

                var newRow = addRow.clone();


                $('input', addRow).val('');


                $('td:first-child', newRow).html(newRowNum);



                $('input', newRow).each(function(i){
                    var newID = newRowNum + '_' + i;
                    $(this).attr('id',newID).attr('name',newID);
                });


                addRow.before(newRow);


                $('a.remove', newRow).click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    return false;               
                });


                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="back.php" method="get"   >
            <table id="tabdata">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Row</th>
                        <th>Cell 1</th>
                        <th>Cell 2</th>
                        <th>Cell 3</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a id="addnew" href="">Add</a></td>
                        <td><input id="n0_1" name="n0_1" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input id="n0_2" name="n0_2" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input id="n0_3" name="n0_3" type="text" /></td>

                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <input id="go" name="go" type="submit" value=" Save " />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Please explain further.

Comment: The above code sends data to a back.php page ..
my question is how do i recieve data in that page ..
if i know the number of inputs cmming then i can get it via loop. but i don't know the number of inputs cmming... it is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a hidden input that contains the current number of rows.  Set the value on the click event handler for #go.

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var numRows =$('#tabdata tbody tr').length;
    $('#myHiddenInput').val(numRows);
});
```

Comment: Well This code works perfectly fine for input fields.
But not i am having 1 <select> option also in between..
how to modify it for that please tell